# This simple piece of html shows pretty erratic behaviour in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

This simple piece of html shows pretty erratic behaviour in chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/utb4p0wr/

HTML

```
<table class=universe>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table class=upper><tr><td>upper</td></tr></table>
    <table class=lower><tr><td>lower</td></tr></table>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
html, body, .universe {
    height: 100%;
}
.upper {
    height: 50%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.lower {
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

1) Look at it in a big window.

2) Shrink the window. The red table escapes the screen on top!

3) Shrink the window further. At one point it suddenly snaps and becomes tiny.

In Firefox all this does not happen.

Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: I have got Chrome 38 and I don't see anything jumping

Comment: Right before the jump: http://i.imgur.com/sEmGdHk.png

Comment: Right after the jump: http://i.imgur.com/7wIaXsn.png

Comment: Are you using tables for layout? Because if you are, there are actually better, less buggy solutions than tables. Table cell dimensions are calculated strangely, and might not be handled uniformly across browsers.

Comment: It's erratic, I suspect, because your sizing is not logical. One cell is 50% but the other is 300px, but the whole table is 100%. No wonder the browser gets confused. **If the table is more than 600px tall, the numbers don't work.**

Comment: ahb: Can you compare what you see to the screenshots? Here it happens in Chrome 38 on windows and linux.

Comment: It does happen. You have set your top table to be 50% and bottom one to be a static 300px. When you resize the bottom 300px table maintains its size whereas the top 50% gets squashed to accommodate the bottom table. Like @Paulie_D said the browser gets confused. What are you trying to build there has to be a better way...

Comment: ahb: it's not about building something. i'm trying to figure out what the rules are behind this behaviour. that the upper table gets squashed might be explainable. depending on what the 50% refer to. im not sure. ff handles it differently. the sudden jump and that it overflows the top of the window look like pretty random behaviour.